# What appendTo in sortable does?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I created a very simple example to check what appendTo is doing exactly:

```
<ul id="sortable">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#sortable").sortable({ appendTo: document.body });
</script>
```

When I'm trying to select one of the items, and check Developer Tools in chrome to see if it moves (append to) to body during the drag .. but it didn't ..

What does appendTo actually do?

Comment: It actually should place helper element to the element you specify. I think there can be a problem with Chrome developer tools.

Comment: @maximgladkov so it should actually move out the dragged element from #sortable and append it to Body while dragging? what after invalid dragging?

Comment: It will create a helper element with all the elements of original one. And of course, removing old one from the container. If drag is invalid, it will return back your original element.

Comment: @maximgladkov thank you, u could replied in an answer maybe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually should place helper element to the element you specify. I think there can be a problem with Chrome developer tools.

It will create a helper element with all the elements of original one. And of course, removing old one from the container. If drag is invalid, it will return back your original element.

Hope it helps!